# How did Cochrane intend to return to Earth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-first-contact

The flight of the *Phoenix* will undoubtedly be one of humanity's greatest achievements in the years to come. A re-purposed nuclear missile (and it's nice to know we'll have some left over) with a titanium casing will escape atmosphere, jettison its first stage then shoot to Warp 1 (old system).

[image: The Phoenix]
<sup>([image from Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/File:Phoenix_space.jpg) - fair use)</sup>

Fortunately for Zephram Cochrane, the partially-assimilated Enterprise-E will be on hand to help recover the craft and its crew (and we can throw away Prime Directive problems since Cochrane will literally see the Enterprise in space, and finds out all about its crew's origins).

[image: Enterprise-E as seen from the Phoenix]
<sup>(Still from *First Contact* - I'm hoping that this is fair use as well)</sup>

However, it seems unlikely that full, safe control of the Enterprise could be regained in time to assist with this project before life support on the *Phoenix* expired. Furthermore, Cochrane will have no way of knowing that time travellers from the future will be on hand to help. He lives in a remote area of a decimated United States, with no obvious support system in place to chopper a crew out and recover him and his co-pilots from who-knows-where after re-entry and landing.

Was Cochrane planning to just drop in on dry land near Bozeman, Montana in the charred remains of his crew capsule? If so, how was the full *Phoenix* recovered for later display in the Smithsonian? If Cochrane had access to futuristic technology such as impulse engines, he certainly didn't use it to launch in the first place (though the turn made by the *Phoenix* after dropping out of warp the first time suggests it had some manner of thrusters).

Comment: Maybe the Vulcans originally saved him.

Comment: He was planning to sell it before all hell broke loose, wasn't he?  It had to have some manner of re-entry available.

Comment: Considering the choice of chassis, most likely he planned to leave the engine in orbit, and land a command module in a manner similar to the Soyuz capsules.

Comment: @Irishpanda: Okay; land it where?

Comment: Presumably, near the launch point in Bozeman, MT. Lots of wide open flat space out there, similar to the Russian steppes that they land the Soyuz craft on. Remember, Soyuz set down on land, and not the sea-based splashdown of American craft.

Comment: @Irishpanda: Interesting; I didn't know that. I can confirm that Soyuz tend to come in on land. Then I guess it's only a question of how he intended to get a reasonably close landing site with a reasonably good degree of confidence (because, again, unlikely to have a recovery team standing by) ... add on "as it happens, the Enterprise helped" to explain how the entire craft was recovered, and you're there. Does potentially beg the question, though, why did nobody else question this in the Star Trek universe before ST:FC? Suggests to me he had a plausible full-vehicle recovery plan in fact.

Comment: As @Radhil mentioned, he planned to sell the thing, so he must have had some recovery plan in mind. It is also entirely possible he did have a recovery team in place. He relied on a variety of international finances to get the thing built, so it would stand to reason some of those funds would go to recovering the command capsule after touchdown.

Comment: @Irishpanda: _"He relied on a variety of international finances to get the thing built"_ Oh, I don't remember that part.